# Text vertical alignment in sketch different than in css

Tags: css, text-alignment, sketch-3

I know this is a very common problem, but I have yet to find a canonical solution for it.
I have a design created in Sketch, and when I use the exact font, font-size and line-height in css, the browser renders the text differently.

**Example:**

Here is how the text is rendered in Sketch:
[image: Text alignment in sketch]

See how the text is beautifully aligned with the icon?

Now, I render the exact same thing in the browser. I am using flex's `align-items: center` for vertical alignment of the text with the icon. But, since the text is not vertically aligned inside it's bounding box, the alignment is off.

[image: Text alignment in the browser]

I know that the [Braid design system](https://github.com/seek-oss/braid-design-system) handles this by [cropping the whitespace](https://twitter.com/markdalgleish/status/1182836856997593089) around text nodes. While this looks like a very nice approach, it also feels a bit overkill for a problem that seems to be so basic.

So my question is: Is there a solution for aligning the two? Either make CSS render text like sketch, or, make sketch render text like CSS?

Thanks to all that took the time to read this!